# How do i return the value of count from my while loop in Java

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm new to coding and I'm required to have a return statement but I'm struggling on how to return the values of count from my while loop. I put a link of picture of what I'm getting plus my code is below.

Also I added a printout of "is factor of number " + count just so I can see what count is doing during the while loop. What I really want to do is return these values so when I hit run these values and only these values appear.

Here is my code:

```
package allFactors;

public class AllFactors {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(printFactors(25));
    }

    public static int printFactors(int number) {
        if (number < 1) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Value ");
        }

        int count = 0;
        while (count <= number) {
            count++;

            if (number % count == 0) {
                System.out.println(count + " is factor of number ");
                continue;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

my CURRENT output is as follows:

1 is factor of number

5 is factor of number

25 is factor of number

26

- i only put system.out.println(count + " is factor of number "); BECAUSE 
  i want to see what my count value is, NOW i dont want to return count; because that just gives me 26, i want to JUST return 1, 5 and 25. Because these numbers are all factors of 25; once i can do this i will delete my  system.out.println(count + " is factor of number "); line of code because it is not necessary. I hope this question make sense

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

1

5

25

Comment: please add your current and desired output.

Comment: my current output is: 1 is factor of number
                                  5 is factor of number
                                  25 is factor of number
                                  26

desired output is: 1
                             5
                             25

Comment: for some reason i cannot type or copy paste my output in more understandable and realistic view, i added outcome in original question and it is pretty close to what i see on screen, i hope you can see it there and it helps.

Comment: A function in java can return only one value/object. If you want to return multiple values from a function, you must create a Collection of all the values and return that.

Answer (score 1):

Here you want to return all the factors of the number : 
So you can use the list to store all the factors and then return that list and print it, code is this -

```
    package allFactors;

    public class AllFactors {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           printFactors(32).forEach(System.out::println);
       }

       public static List<Integer> printFactors(int number) {
           if (number < 1) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Value ");
           }
           List<Integer> all_factors = new ArrayList<>();
           int count = 0;
           while (count <= number) {
               count++;
               if (number % count == 0) {
                   all_factors.add(count);
                   System.out.println(count + " is factor of number ");
                   continue;
               }
           }
          return all_factors;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` is like the output of your function. In the code you said return 0, so no matter what, it will only print 0. Change it to `return count;` is how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

just return the count from the end of the method as follows

```
public static int printFactors(int number) {
    if (number < 1) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Value ");
    }

    int count = 0;
    while (count <= number) {
        count++;

        if (number % count == 0) {
            System.out.println(count + " is factor of number ");
            continue;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: please look back at my question i just updated it, thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return all values you need to use some collection please check below code

```
package allFactors;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AllFactors {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(printFactors(32));
}

public static List<Integer> printFactors(int number) {
    if (number < 1) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Value ");
    }
    List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<>();
    int count = 0;
    while (count <= number) {
        count++;

        if (number % count == 0) {
            factors.add(count);
            System.out.println(count + " is factor of number ");
        }
    }
    return factors;
 }
}
```